# Alternative to PHP's associative arrays in JAVA

Tags: java, php, arrays, string, associative-array

In PHP I could use an array with strings as keys. eg
$some_array["cat"] = 123;
$some_array["dog"] = 456;
I just switched to Java and I can't find a data structure capable of doing this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are describing is an [*associative* array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), also called a table, dictionary, or map.

In Java, you want the `Map` interface, and probably the [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) class as the implementation.

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
myMap.put("cat", 123);

Integer value = myMap.get("cat"); //123
```

Comment: Ah. Thank you. Actually I was using a HashMap, but I wrote some part of my code wrong so that the map wasn't behaving like a HashMap. Damn these tiny mistakes...

Comment: @someguy What was it behaving like?!

Answer (score 2):

You would use one of the [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementations such as [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), most likely a [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 1):

The data structure you are after is `Map`. I believe its an abstract class so you'll have to use one of its concrete subclasses like `HashMap<?>`

Answer (score 0):

As many people said, a Map is what you are looking for. If that was your choice, do not forget to reimplement hashcode() and equals(). Take a look because is a must: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html